# map through nested children components in react

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to add a new property to a nested child element in a top level component.

My higher level component is called Photo.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

export default class Photo extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.onHandleLoad = this.onHandleLoad.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      isLoaded:false
    }
  }

  onHandleLoad(event){
    this.setState({
      isLoaded:true
    })
  }

  render(){
    const {children} = this.props;
    return(
      <div className="photo-container">
        {children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**Here is how I add children to it.**

```
   <Photo >
      <Link to='/bla' className="slide-show-link">
        <img src={photo.photo} alt={`${photo.title} photo`}/>
      </Link>
    </Photo>
```

Its not always the same children added. Sometimes it might be more levels to the nesting but it always has an **img** element.
I want a way to be able to map through all the nested elements and find the img element and add custom props to it.

The prop I want to add is onLoad={this.onHandleLoad) so it will call the onHandleLoad inside Photo with the right scope.

I've looked at React.Children.map but that only returns the first element  and not the nested elements. img could be 1 level down or more.
How can I do this. was looking into recursion mapping but not sure thats the way to go. Is there a built in method that handles this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to do this might be to use something like redux and dispatch an action for every image load. But it would require a lot of refactoring if you are not currently using it.

There is another way that fits here pretty well which is [context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html). There are [many warnings about using context](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/context.html#why-not-to-use-context), but since you're only providing a callback there isn't very much risk.

Context will allow your parent component to pass down the callback any number of levels without having to pass props through each one.

-

First add `childContextTypes` and `getChildContext` to your parent component:

```
export default class Photo extends Component {
  static childContextTypes = {
    onHandleLoad: PropTypes.func
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoaded: false
    }
  }

  getChildContext() {
    return {
      onHandleLoad: this.onHandleLoad
    };
  }

  onHandleLoad = (event) => {
    this.setState({
      isLoaded: true
    })
  }

  render() {
    const {children} = this.props;
    return(
      <div className="photo-container">
        {children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Then you will need a child component wrapper around your `<img>`s to hook into the parent context by using `contextTypes`:

```
class PhotoImage extends Component {
  static contextTypes = {
    onHandleLoad: PropTypes.func
  }

  static propTypes = {
    photo: PropTypes.string,
    title: PropTypes.string
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <img
        src={photo}
        alt={`${title} photo`}
        onLoad={this.context.onHandleLoad}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh this is great thanks. Hopefully they wont remove context in the next few releases. I was staying away from it but you are right its the easiest way.